# Difference between calling Rails mail’s collector block with and without render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are the following equivalent? if not, what’s the practical difference between them? Is **render** needed in this case?

```
mail(to: 'someone@example.com', from: 'me@example.com', subject: 'Hi') do |format|
  format.text  { render plain: 'text' }
  format.html { render html: '<html></html>'.html_safe }
end
```

vs

```
mail(to: 'someone@example.com', from: 'me@example.com', subject: 'Hi') do |format|
  format.text  { 'text' }
  format.html { '<html></html>' }
end
```

I read part of Rails action mailer source code and it seems that, in this case, render would simply populate options[:body] which is then added to the responses array @responses << options. I also compared the email source generated by both and they looked the same.

https://github.com/carlhuda/rails-bundler-test/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L679

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/collector.rb#L28

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b93fff8af32ef5e91f4ec3cfffb081d0553faf0/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb#L7